# Wordpress how to auto-generat pages programmatically when custom WordPress theme is installed and assign them to blog page and front page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So I have a Custom WordPress Theme I am developing and upon installation of it in a new WordPress setup I would like a MENU auto-generated along with 3 pages, i.e:

- **Products**
- **Policy**
- **Services**

that is my theme will heavily depend on.

I will already have 3 template pages made for these in the custom theme files, i.e:

- **page-products.php**
- **page-policy.php**
- **page-services.php**

So when the theme is installed these are auto-created so it's a no brainer for the client.

I know Twig but very little PHP and if some could write this up so I could just drop it into my `functions.php` file.

I would be very, very grateful and many thanks!!

---

**EDIT**
**Additional questions**
Also I will be having a Home and a News page auto created as well. Would there be a quick code to auto set these up as the default Homepage and default Posts page? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Is this maybe not practical to do?

Comment: Also wondering since I already have these **page-products.php, page-policy.php and page-services.php** templates made could I some how just link and display them without having to manually generate these pages in the wp backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `after_switch_theme` action hook and `wp_insert_post` function to achieve what you're looking for.

> [`after_switch_theme`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_switch_theme/)

> [`wp_insert_post`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

---

1. So to generate these three pages, first, we create a function that incorporates `wp_insert_post` function. Our custom function will take two arguments and first checks whether the page you're trying to create exists or not. If the page exists it will return `false`, otherwise, it'll create the page and return the id of that page.

> The following code goes to the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```php
function your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content)
{
    $page_obj = get_page_by_title($page_title, 'OBJECT', 'page');

    if ($page_obj) {

        return false;

        exit();

    }

    $page_args = array(

        'post_type'      => 'page',

        'post_status'    => 'publish',

        'post_title'     => ucwords($page_title),

        'post_name'      => strtolower(trim($page_title)),

        'post_content'   => $page_content,

    );

    $page_id = wp_insert_post($page_args);

    return $page_id;

}
```

2. Now, on `after_switch_theme` action hook we run another custom function. This time we will create an associative array to hold our `page titles` as well as `page contents`. Then we feed that array to the function we created above using a `foreach` loop.

> The following code also goes to the `functions.php` of your active theme.

```php
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation');

function my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation()
{

    $pages_array = array(

        'products page' => '<h3>Hello from products page</h3>',

        'policy page'   => '<h3>Hello from policy page</h3>',

        'services page' => '<h3>Hello from services page</h3>'

    );

    foreach ($pages_array as $page_title => $page_content) {

        $current_page = your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content);

        if (false != $current_page) {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

?>
                <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "Done! {$page_title} has been created"; ?></p>

                </div>

            <?php

            });

        } else {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

            ?>
                <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "{$page_title} was not created! Check whether it already exists"; ?></p>

                </div>

<?php

            });

        }

    }

}
```

Note that i used `admin_notices` action hook to give the user a visual message.

if generating those pages was successful, then user sees the following messages:

[image]

If, on the other hand, those pages were not generated or they already exist, then the user will see the following messages:

[image]

Now we have our pages created, you could see them on the pages menu on the admin screen:

[image]

And here's the page content for example:

[image]

---

Now, you could take this one step further and create more complex templates and feed them to that assortative array.

So for example, you have `page-products.php`, `page-policy.php` and `page-services.php` files inside a folder called, let's say, `inc`. So your folder structure would be something like this:

```
Your-theme-folder
    |
    |css-folder
    |   |
    |   some-css.css
    |
    |javascript-folder
    |   |
    |   some-js.js
    |
    |inc-folder
        |
        page-products.php
        page-policy.php  
        page-services.php
```

Then your associative array would be something like this:

```php
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation');

function my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation()
{

    $products_page_title = 'products page'; 

    $policy_page_title   = 'policy page';

    $services_page_title = 'services page';

    $products_page_content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '\inc\page-products.php');

    $policy_page_content   = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '\inc\page-policy.php');

    $services_page_content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '\inc\page-services.php');

    $pages_array = array(

        $products_page_title => $products_page_content,

        $policy_page_title   => $policy_page_content,

        $services_page_title => $services_page_content

    );

    foreach ($pages_array as $page_title => $page_content) {

        $current_page = your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content);

        if (false != $current_page) {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

?>
                <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "Done! {$page_title} has been created"; ?></p>

                </div>

            <?php

            });

        } else {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

            ?>

                <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "{$page_title} was not created! Check whether it already exists"; ?></p>

                </div>

<?php

            });

        }

    }

}
```

Let me know if you have any question.

---

**Answer to the additional questions**

Yes it's feasible to do so. Wordpress keeps track of the `blog posts page` under `page_for_posts` option. It also store the info for `front page` under `page_on_front` and `show_on_front` options. So to assign your pages to the `blog` and `front` pages, you'll update those options.

So when the custom function fires off in the `after_switch_theme` action hook, after the `foreach` loop you could add the following code to assign your pages:

```php
$blog_page = get_page_by_title('news', 'OBJECT', 'page');

if ($blog_page) {

    update_option('page_for_posts', $blog_page->ID);

}

$front_home_page = get_page_by_title('home', 'OBJECT', 'page');

if ($front_home_page) {

    update_option('page_on_front', $front_home_page->ID);

    update_option('show_on_front', 'page');

}
```

> [`get_page_by_title`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/)

So the entire custom function for the `after_switch_theme` action hook would be something like this:

```php
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation');

function my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation()
{

    $pages_array = array(

        'products page' => '',

        'policy page'   => '',

        'services page' => ''

    );

    foreach ($pages_array as $page_title => $page_content) {

        $current_page = your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content);

        if (false != $current_page) {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

?>

                <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "Done! {$page_title} has been created"; ?></p>

                </div>

            <?php

            });

        } else {

            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {

            ?>

                <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">

                    <p><?php echo "{$page_title} was not created! Check whether it already exists"; ?></p>

                </div>

<?php

            });

        }

    }

    $blog_page = get_page_by_title('news', 'OBJECT', 'page');

    if ($blog_page) {

        update_option('page_for_posts', $blog_page->ID);

    }

    $front_home_page = get_page_by_title('home', 'OBJECT', 'page');

    if ($front_home_page) {

        update_option('page_on_front', $front_home_page->ID);

        update_option('show_on_front', 'page');

    }

}
```

Comment: I so appreciate your answer, everything seems to be working fine and will mark your soon, I do have a few questions so if I don't want and <h3>Hello</h3> content I would just do this then `'work page' => '',`

Comment: Also I will be having a `Home` and a `News` page auto created as well would there be a any quick code to auto set these as the default `Homepage` and default `Posts page` respectfully while we are at it anyway?  Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: For your first question, yes you could leave the content blank. You don't have to use `<h3>` tags. The `<h3>Hello</h3>` was just an example.

Comment: For your second question, yes there is a way to do that as well. i just updated my answer.

Comment: That worked right out of the box, many thanks for all you hard work and great answers!! I would have another question (and maybe it's for another post) but all of these pages really are just static pages that no one will put content on as there are templates written for each one of them in my theme - would there be anyway they could all be hidden from the dashboard so the client does not fool with them or what is the proper way to handle something like this?

Comment: For your question, yes there are some workarounds for that too. It depends how you want to set up your theme structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236579/discussion-between-shrockco-and-ruvee).

Comment: Quick Follow-up question, how easy would it be to have custom slugs created for each page ie, `Tool Brands` would have a slug of `brands`

Comment: We're already defining a slug for those pages. In the `page_args` array, there is an argument called `post_name` which would be your page slug. Like so: `'post_name' => 'brands'`. If you need more detailed explanation, you could go ahead and open up a new question and send me the `url`, then we'll talk about it in more details. There is not much room left here! :)

Comment: Here you go: [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69277496/how-to-auto-assign-custom-page-slugs-to-wordpress-pages-automatically) and thanks so much for any help :)