# How to auto assign custom page slugs to WordPress pages automatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Thanks to [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354795/wordpress-how-to-auto-generat-pages-programmatically-when-custom-wordpress-theme/68987486?noredirect=1#comment122425045_68987486) I have this php code to auto generate some pages upon my custom theme's activation (Works great) however I would like to also be able to also customize the slugs that get created for each page for example for the page `Tool Brands` I would like the slug to be just `brands` This is important for a few reasons, 1) For ease of customer use [www.domain.com/brands](http://www.domain.com/brands) and 2) My page titles are auto generated based on the page name so I would like to keep the `Tool Brands` as the page name but in this case it would also create a slug `tool-brands` which I don't want.

Thanks for any help - also having it clearly wrote out for me would be a big help as I barely know PHP.

Code is below and also on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/pHeAdpmB)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
function your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content)
{
    $page_obj = get_page_by_title($page_title, 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($page_obj) {
 
        return false;
 
        exit();
 
    }
 
    $page_args = array(
 
        'post_type'      => 'page',
 
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
 
        'post_title'     => ucwords($page_title),
 
        'post_name'      => strtolower(trim($page_title)),
 
        'post_content'   => $page_content,
 
    );
 
    $page_id = wp_insert_post($page_args);
 
    return $page_id;
 
}
// Second Section of Code
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation');
 
function my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation()
{
 
  $pages_array = array(
    'Home' => '',    
    'News' => '',
    'Products' => '',
    'Policy' => '',
    'Services' => '',
    'Tool Brands' => '',
    
    );
 
    foreach ($pages_array as $page_title => $page_content) {
 
        $current_page = your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content);
 
        if (false != $current_page) {
 
            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {
 
?>
 
                <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
 
                    <p><?php echo "Done! {$page_title} has been created"; ?></p>
 
                </div>
 
            <?php
 
            });
 
        } else {
 
            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {
 
            ?>
 
                <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
 
                    <p><?php echo "{$page_title} was not created! Check whether it already exists"; ?></p>
 
                </div>
 
<?php
 
            });
 
        }
 
    }
 
    $blog_page = get_page_by_title('news', 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($blog_page) {
 
        update_option('page_for_posts', $blog_page->ID);
 
    }
 
    $front_home_page = get_page_by_title('home', 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($front_home_page) {
 
        update_option('page_on_front', $front_home_page->ID);
 
        update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: The `post_name` parameter is what gets mapped to the slug

Comment: What would I have to change to be able to set my own custom slugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more variable to your_theme_create_page() function with slug.
And change array format to multidimensional

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
function your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content, $new_post_name, $new_post_status)
{
    $page_obj = get_page_by_title($page_title, 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($page_obj) {
 
        return false;
 
        exit();
 
    }
 
    $page_args = array(
 
        'post_type'      => 'page',
 
        'post_status'    => $new_post_status,
 
        'post_title'     => ucwords($page_title),
 
        'post_name'      => $new_post_name,
 
        'post_content'   => $page_content,
      
 
    );
 
    $page_id = wp_insert_post($page_args);
 
    return $page_id;
 
}
// Second Section of Code
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation');
 
function my_custom_pages_on_theme_activation()
{
 
$pages_array = array(
    "1" => array(
        "post_title" => 'Home title here',
        "post_content" => 'Home content here',
        "post_name" => 'home_slug_here',
        "post_status" => 'private',
    ),          
    "2" => array(
        "post_title" => 'News title here',
        "post_content" => 'News content here',
        "post_name" => 'news_slug_here',
    ),       
    "3" => array(
        "post_title" => 'title here 3',
        "post_content" => 'content here 3',
        "post_name" => 'slug_here3',
    ),    
);
 
    foreach ($pages_array as $page_array) {
 $page_title = $page_array['post_title'];
 $page_content = $page_array['post_content'];
 $new_post_name = $page_array['post_name'];
 if(isset($page_array['post_status'])) {
 $new_post_status= $page_array['post_status'];
 } else  {
 $new_post_status = 'publish';
 }
        $current_page = your_theme_create_page($page_title, $page_content, $new_post_name, $new_post_status );
 
        if (false != $current_page) {
 
            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {
 
?>
 
                <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
 
                    <p><?php echo "Done! {$page_title} has been created"; ?></p>
 
                </div>
 
            <?php
 
            });
 
        } else {
 
            add_action('admin_notices', function () use ($page_title) {
 
            ?>
 
                <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
 
                    <p><?php echo "{$page_title} was not created! Check whether it already exists"; ?></p>
 
                </div>
 
<?php
 
            });
 
        }
 
    }
 
    $blog_page = get_page_by_title('news', 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($blog_page) {
 
        update_option('page_for_posts', $blog_page->ID);
 
    }
 
    $front_home_page = get_page_by_title('home', 'OBJECT', 'page');
 
    if ($front_home_page) {
 
        update_option('page_on_front', $front_home_page->ID);
 
        update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I want to say a huge thank-you for helping me out on this one! The code works right out of the box!

Comment: So I have a post name `Develop` that I want published as "private" but this is not working for me in the array: `"post_visibility" => 'private',` Also see [link here](https://prnt.sc/1ux7bws)

Comment: You need "post_status" => 'private',

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try that to no avail, seems like maybe its being overwritten by the earlier statement? See [link](https://prnt.sc/1uxulat)

Comment: Yes, i updated code

Comment: Thank-you, I had to add another the $new_post_status to line 143 [SeeLink](https://prnt.sc/1uykfa5) and now everything works properly but throws this error yet: `Undefined index: post_status` [ErrorLink](https://prnt.sc/1uyl4d8)

Comment: I update code, try now

Comment: Its still giving me an erro of `Undefined variable: new_post_status ... line 139` [See Link](https://prnt.sc/1v1f621)

Comment: Ok, try updated code, what PHP version at your Wordpress ?

Comment: I am now using PHP7.4.1 and had to add `"post_status" => '',` to each array to get it working, was still throwing that same error. Not sure what the deal was?

Comment: Ok, try updated code

Comment: Okay that worked now, thanks again for the updated code, NOTE: I did have to add `$new_post_status` about 2/3 down the page or it would just [complain](https://prnt.sc/1v291ex)